# How to compute Voronoi tesselation based on manhattan distance in R

Tags: r, geometry, distance, computational-geometry, voronoi

I am trying to compute a Voronoi tesselation in 2D with the **Manhattan** distance in `R`.

**Ideally** this would be a function that takes a set of two-dimensional points and outputs a list of polygons that partition the space. I am not certain what representations of Voronoi tesselations are standard.

There are of course many ways to do this with the Euclidean metric (packages like `deldir` and `qhull` make this very easy), but I haven't found a way to do this for the manhattan distance. A search using `sos`'s `findFn('voronoi')` also yielded no results.

Comment: to be clear - `findFn('voronoi')` yields a TON of results, just none that seemed to work with the manhattan distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Info: [taxicabgeometry.net](http://taxicabgeometry.net/)

Interactive: [Manhattan-metric Voronoi diagram(Click version)](http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/emancli.html)

I've been rolling [my own in python](https://github.com/bobbysoon/TaxiVoronoi), and can sum up the basics here:
Between neighboring centroids is a perpendicular line, in manhattan metric - two rays and a 45 degree diagonal most likely, if the centroids are randomly generated, but a straight horizontal, vertical, or 45 degree diagonal line may also occur. Given a set of such lines for every centroid pair, the edges separating the regions are among them. Collect intersect points of each pair of lines which are equal-distant (within an epsilon), in manhattan metric, to it's 3 nearest centroids. Also collect the two mid points of the 45 degree diagonal which are similarly equal-distant to their nearest *two* centroids. The outer polies won't be closed. How to deal with them depends on what you need. The poly borders and border verts will need sorting, so your polies aren't a zigzagged mess. Winding order can be determined if they should be clockwise or other. More can be done, just depends on what you need.

Unfortunately, this gets exponentially slower the more points are involved. The intersecting of every bisector to every other bisector is the bottleneck. I've been attempting an insertion method, with some success, but . Now I'm thinking to try first creating a nearest-neighbor linkage between the centroids. If the neighbors are known, the bisectors to intersect will be minimal, and many centroids can be computed quickly.

Anyway, the brute-force approach does work:
[image]

The point near the cursor is actually 2 points of a tiny diagonal. It's a precise method, but more complicated than it first seems. The java code from the interactive link above may be faster, but was difficult to get solid and precise geometry from.

Sorry, I dont know R.

Comment: The Java code is *awful* :/. Dozens of spurious instance variables, bizarre reimplementations of functions like Math.abs and Math.pow, great monolithic swodges of code, dead and/or useless code and variables everywhere ...

In case it's of use to anyone, I've got a *slightly* tidier version of the code at https://gist.github.com/phlummox/95dfc36f500f2fce4f7033c67d46e4fc  

 
edit: Oh, and the method for Manhattan distance is labelled as "Euclidean distance". jfc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is about finding the maximum area of a square that match inside a circumcircle (of a triangle). The equation for such a square abs(x)+abs(y)=r (www.mathematische-basteleien.de/taxicabgeometry.htm). When you have a mesh of triangles the voronoi diagram is the dual.