# Voronoi diagram in Manhattan metric

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

I am using `scipy.spatial` for visualizations of Voronoi diagrams. However, the distance metric that is used here is Euclidean (L2). I am looking for a way of Manhattan (L1) metric on my Voronoi diagram. Is there an easy (more or less) way of doing that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[1.5, 1.], [3.5, 1.], [5., 2.], [2.5, 3.], [3.5, 1.], [4., 4.]])
    
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
vor = Voronoi(points)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot('111')
ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'o', color='k')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 9])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 9])
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax)
```

Basically I'd like to get something similar but in L1 metric.

[image]

I have found the `scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock` that can handle the metric of interest but not entirely sure how can I implement it so that it works?

Comment: There is this python implementation of the Manhattan Voronoi: https://github.com/bobbysoon/TaxiVoronoi . I didn't check if/how it works, but maybe it'll help you. (I found it through this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623208)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't able to get that to work.

Comment: @bajun65537 wondering if the solution below worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a github repo containing a Python package called [`voronoiz`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/voronoiz) that includes the functions `voronoi_l1` (for computing the polygons of an L1 Voronoi diagram) and `voronoi_grid` (for computing an image of the Voronoi diagram for any distance metric supported by `scipy.spatial.cdist`).

The implementations use brute-force, O(n²) algorithms, so it probably won't work well if you use it with millions of points, but for a small to moderate number of points, you can use it to make nice plots.

For example, these animations of a Voronoi diagram for a set of 10 points, one of which moves around in a circle, are made with `voronoi_grid` combined with `write_apng` from the [`numpngw`](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/) library:

L1 metric:

[image: city block metric animation]

Minkowksi metric, p=2 (i.e. standard Euclidean metric):

[image: minkowksi p=2 metric animation]

Minkowski metric, p=4:

[image: minkowski p=4 metric animation]

Here's the script that generates the animations:

```
import numpy as np
from voronoiz import voronoi_grid
from numpngw import write_apng


xmin = 0
xmax = 5
ymin = 0
ymax = 5

points = np.array([[0.00, 0.00],
                   [1.00, 4.51],
                   [1.20, 0.30],
                   [2.50, 2.60],
                   [2.40, 0.80],
                   [4.40, 3.30],
                   [1.95, 3.00],
                   [3.71, 1.90],
                   [4.50, 3.66],
                   [4.67, 0.21]])

gridsize = 299

for kwargs in [dict(metric='cityblock'),
               dict(metric='minkowski', p=2),
               dict(metric='minkowski', p=4)]:
    imgs = []
    for theta in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 250, endpoint=False):
        # points[0] will travel about a circle.
        points[0] = 2.5 + 1.5*np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])
        img = voronoi_grid(points, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax,
                           gridsize=(gridsize, gridsize),
                           **kwargs)
        img = (160//(len(points)+1)*img + 64).astype(np.uint8)
        img[img == 64] = 0
        for x, y in points:
            i = int(gridsize*(x - xmin)/(xmax - xmin))
            j = int(gridsize*(y - ymin)/(ymax - ymin))
            img[j-1:j+2, i-1:i+2] = 255
        img = np.pad(img, pad_width=1, mode='constant', constant_values=255)
        imgs.append(img)

    tag = '_'.join(f"{key}_{value}" for key, value in kwargs.items())
    write_apng(f'animation_{tag}.png', imgs, delay=100)
```

Comment: Sweet! I believe it works.

Answer (score 2):

If visualisation and computation of areas are your only requirements you can use this pip library called [mcvoronoi](https://pypi.org/project/mcvoronoi/) we did a while back. This is based on monte-carlo sampling. I added an option to change the distance metric for this answer. The updated version (*with distance metric option*) is not published on pip yet, but you can use the github master branch. The usage is shown below:

- Clone the [repository](https://github.com/abcnishant007/mcvoronoi) in your current directory
- Run `python example.py`

The example.py consists of this basic line:

```
lat_lon_area, mean_percentage_error = voronoi_area(points,voronoi_plot_enabled=True, NUM_COLORS=5, metric='manhattan')
```

The images are saved as shown below:

You can of course make them super crisp by increasing the number of points in sampling. An error plot showing the error in area calculation is generated as well.
[image]

You might want to use more colors but if you have a sufficiently large number of regions, slightly more than [4 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) are usually enough.